# How to show default image if image isn't loaded properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've came up with [this solution (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dimetriusifua/fz89zka1/) - implement `$.error` function and change image `src` attribute, but seams that this function is not always called and sometimes I get this [image: default image] image with `alt` text instead of one I provided. I use this jquery code to update images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').error(function () {
        var defaultSrc = $(this).data('default-src');
        $(this).attr('src', defaultSrc);
    });
});
```

`data-default-src` attribute is also provided for each image. Is there some more advanced and certain **jquery** solution?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/93017/3639582.

Comment: @ShaunakD, it's better, but now default image is displayed way to often, original image is displayed after page refresh though...

Comment: @RohitArora `img` selector means select all `img` elements on page

Comment: @ShaunakD, no, my bad, I used `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`, now it works almost perfect. If you post the answer i'll accept it.

Comment: You used `$(window).load()`. I had referred the existing answer which wasn't mine. So I think you should self-answer and accept.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that even the `$(document).ready` event can be too late to attach the `.error` handler to the imgs. The error event(s) may already have happened before the handler is attached.

As a workaround, you can ensure that the image's `src` is not set until after the `.error` handler is in place, for example, like this :

**HTML**

```
<img id="1" data-src="/bad/path/to/image" data-default-src="good/path/to/image" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').on('error', function () {
        this.src = $(this).data('default-src');
    }).each(function() {
        this.src = $(this).data('src');
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qs1tLqkm/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use .load() for this problem:

```
$(this).load(defaultSrc);
```